# creating a page that displays ID info on a template

Tags: php, mysql, database

Updated with suggestion by others but still seem to be stuck.

I'm using this php code here to display info from my database using the ID. I created a link on my main page that looks like this.

```
<h1><a href="fetch.php?id=<?php echo $row_getDisplay['post_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_getDisplay['title']; ?></a></a></h1>
```

I have so when they click on the title of the article that it takes them to my php fiel which I named fetch.php and the code below is what is in there. I have built this around someone else's work. For some reason I can't get passed the first "else" statement. so I keep getting "you must select a valid location" I'm fairly new to php so I don't really understand why the code is failing.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/XXXXXX.php'); ?>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['id']) ==  false) // check if id has been set 
{ 
echo "You must select a location"; // if not, display this error 
exit; 
} else { 
$id = (int) $_GET['id']; 
if (is_numeric($id) == false) 
**{ 
echo "You must select a valid location."; 
} else {** 

mysql_select_db($database_XXXXXX, $XXXXXX);
$query = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM news WHERE post_id ");

if (MYSQL_NUM_ROWS($query) == "1")

{ 
$fetch = MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY($query); // set $fetch to have the values from the table 
echo "Title: " . $fetch['title'] . "<BR>"; // output the info 
echo "Blog: " . $fetch['blog_entry'] . "<BR>"; // etc... 
echo "Author: " . $fetch['author'] . "<BR>"; // etc... 
} else { 
echo "No match in database found."; // if no match is found, display this error 
} 
} 
}
```

Any help is appreciated. If you are able to find a better solution for me that would be great.

Comment: stop using old `MYSQL_QUERY` and start using `PDO` since ancient mysql_* functions are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process.

Comment: Ditto to what blasterfield says. However given that you mentioned youre maintaining an older code base youre probably not going to be able to swith over anytime soon.

Comment: I didn't realize I was following an old tutorial from 11 years ago.

Comment: okay, i got passed the beginning part, now I get the error, "No match in database found" is the statement above correct in calling the data? I have also tried using mysql_fetch_row and no luck, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldnt use `$HTTP_GET_VARS` its deprecated and unless its turned on it wont be populated. use [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) instead.

`if (isset($_GET['id']) ==  false)`

Comment: why PHP allowed  MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY? I thought it's case-sensitive all this while

Comment: No, functions and methods are not case sensitive though its always good to treat them as they are be cause some libraries that make use of of dynamic methods or function calls are case sensitive - Doctrine is a good example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET` for your if statement:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) ==  false)
```

Also, you need to convert your `$_GET` value to an integer, because it is currently a string.

Right after that if statement above, in the `else`, put this:

```
 $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

That way your `is_numeric()` will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/XXXXXX.php');

if (isset($_GET['id'])) // check if id has been set
 {
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (is_numeric($id) == false)
{
echo "You must select a valid location.";
} else {

mysql_select_db($database_XXXXXX, $XXXXXX);
$query = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM news WHERE locationid = 'news.post_id' ");

if (MYSQL_NUM_ROWS($query) == "1")

{
$fetch = MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY($query); // set $fetch to have the values from the table
echo "Title: " . $fetch['title'] . "<BR>"; // output the info
echo "Blog: " . $fetch['blog_entry'] . "<BR>"; // etc...
echo "Author: " . $fetch['author'] . "<BR>"; // etc...
} else {
echo "No match in database found."; // if no match is found, display this error
}
}
}
else{
echo "You must select a location"; // if not, display this error
exit;
}
?>
```

Also, I need a clarification about `news.post_id`, from where are you grabbing this?

Comment: My primary key is named post_id. I thought that filling in that location with how it was with me homepage would have corrected it. I have followed what you have written and I get pass the first If statement only to get stuck at "you must select a valid location.". I have tried changing id to post_id wonder if they would help. It hasn't.